# Expand image downward vertically CSS to fill space

Tags: html, css

This is most likely a duplicate, but I haven't been able to find anything that is *quite* the same.  I'd like to fill a space downward beneath an image to block text from wrapping completely.  In visual terms:

I have this:

```
| /---\  BLAHBLAH
| |img|  blah
| \---/  blah
| blah
| blah
| ...
```

I want this:

```
| /---\  BLAHBLAH
| |img|  blah
| \---/  blah
|        blah
|        blah
|        ...
```

What do I do?

Comment: make your current html into fiddle and post it.

Comment: Yeah.. please add some code snippet to look at. The doodle won't work :)

Comment: It's a template, but I'll try to make a general example.  [here](http://pastebin.com/4Cvd88Gf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can write like this:

```
<img src="bla.png" style="float:left;" />
<div style="overflow:hidden">Some text</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/HhJML/

Comment: This does not work if a parent div has text-align: left.  But, it works well enough for my purposes (or on its own).

Answer (score 0):

You might well need to play with a few CSS properties here. For example, try

```
display:inline-block;
```

for the image. Or

```
float:right;
```

for the text and

```
float:left;
```

for the image OR both, . Even can try a padding bottom for the image

A more stringent way to do this will be to use a table and add the image and text in two 'td' elements in the same 'tr'

Comment: float:right caused the div to drop down below the image.  display:inline-block did nothing.  Doing both did the same as float:right.

Comment: so why not get a nice little table instead :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should set img css float to left and text to float right.. Something like this

```
<img src="bla.png" style="float:left;" />
<div style="float:right;"><p>Some text</p></div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: unfortunately, float:right just puts the text below the image.

Comment: @astex : if you put the text inside container with inline display it wont put it below the image

Answer (score 0):

Add Float property to both Image and text,add the image into a div and allign to the left and set the div height = 100%.! i guess it will work

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is like:

```
<div class="content-container">
  <p><img src="whatever" /> text text text text text
     text text text text text text text text text text text
     text text text text text text text text text text text
     text text text text text text text text text text text
     text text text </p>
</div>
```

Then there's no way to do it with CSS only. Add some jQuery flavor like:

```
// Loop through all the images
$('.content-container img').each(function(){
    // Get image height
    var imageHeight = $(this).height();
    // Get container's height
    var containerHeight = $(this).parent('.content-container').height();
    // Set image bottom margin to container's height - image height
    jQuery(this).css('margin-bottom', (containerHeight - imageHeight) + 'px');
})
```

Comment: This, unfortunately did absolutely nothing...'padding-bottom' also did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="thumbnail.jpg" width="50" height="50" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ligula arcu, luctus nec elementum quis, condimentum a lectus. Suspendisse potenti. Proin neque diam, dictum ac elementum scelerisque, aliquet eget diam....</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    padding: 0 0 0 75px; /* 75px being the width of the thumbnail + how much space you want to put between it and your text */
    position: relative; /* So the thumbnail is relative to this */
}

.content img {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

[CSS tip: Float an image without text wrapping under it](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/blog/2009/12/10/css-tip-float-an-image-without-text-wrapping-under-it/)

Comment: This scales the image vertically, which is not the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a table then you can solve your problem easily.

Like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="yourImage.jpg" alt="" /></td>
        <td>Your text... blah blah blah..... blah</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can set the width of td as to your requirement to make all your td has the same size.

Comment: As I said in the comments on Riju Mahna's answer (of which yours is a duplicate), tables are gross...

Comment: I didn't see that. You can also try 2 div. Put your text on one div and on the other your image. And make both the div as inline-block and their total width should be equal to the main container. Or you can play with the image bottom-margin as well while the image should be float on left. You can try out these two tricks.